# Python django how i can prevent the duplicate entry of studnumber,email,username(unmae) in registration

Tags: python, django

Python django how i can prevent the duplicate entry of studnumber,email,username(unmae) in registration? i use this code before when it us one full name its work but when I divide it to (nmane),(mname),(nnmae), it always saying duplicate record. even their is no similar record on db

MODELS.py
from django import forms
from django.db import models

```
class newacc(models.Model):
        studnumber=models.IntegerField()
        fname=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        mname=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        lname=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        age=models.IntegerField()
        gender=models.CharField(max_length=1)
        uname=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        email=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        pwd=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        contact=models.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
                 unique_together = ('studnumber','email','uname')
class NewACCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = newacc
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from register.models import newacc
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Q#disjunction sa email and uname:

from register.models import NewACCForm

def Unreg(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = NewACCForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"The New User is save !")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Duplicate Reccord.")
    return render(request,'Registration.html')
```

Comment: You should render the forms.errors in your page. This way you force the system to say there is an issue with a dupicate entry regardless of the exception that is being thrown. Which form errors do you get?

Comment: Surely every record must have a unique student ID, and separately a unique username? Are you trying to set a constraint where each combination of ID, username, and email must be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to make them unique individually !!

Add   unique=True